# Not able to open HTML RMarkdown in browser? [images included]

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am knitting this document to HTML and I want to open it in a browser: See below for what I am trying to achieve
[image]

I want to do this so I can save it and share it with my co-workers, however whenever I click "open in browser" I receive 4 errored out browser tabs see below

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3.
[image]

4.
[image]

Comment: The last three of those messages make it look like a browser problem.  Switch to Firefox or Chrome as your default browser and they might be fixed.  Not sure about the first one, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's the same thing.

Comment: Which commands did you use before? Are html files in your folder?